# Initializing a prefab's instance's variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm currently spawning a instance of a prefab GameObject, and I want to initialize some of its variables. Usually I would use FindObjectOfType, however the objects I want to attach to it don't have a type, and are pretty much just empty GameObjects with a few children. I feel like the answer should be incredibly obvious, but I can't wrap my head around a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I forgot to mention that the GameObjects I want to apply to the instance's variables are inactive at the time I want to do so.

Comment: I think you are better off asking at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: So if it is empty objects you mean you want to apply a certain transformation to it? Otherwise what values are we talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if my question wasn't super clear, but I managed to find a solution. I basically put the objects I want to set as the variables in parent object which is always active, then through the script I get the parent object, and finally I get its first child, which would be the object I wanted in the first place:

```
GameObject variable;
GameObject variableParent;

private void Start()
{
    variableParent = GameObject.Find("variableParentName");
    variable = variableParent.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are instantiating the object then wanting to set the variables, then just spawn the object and grab the reference.

```
YourScriptHere tmp = Instantiate(yourObject).GetComponent<YourScriptHere>();
tmp.SetTheFieldHereEqualTo = someValue;
```

If you do not want to just set references to an object you are spawning, can you clarify your question a bit?